# Overflow button on toolbar change color

Tags: android, android-layout

I would like to change color of my overflow button (3 dots) on toolbar but i have a problem with this... I check few topics and i found a solutions... but it work only on Android 5.0 and higher... 
Of course I can change it using colorPrimary but it's not a solutions for me.. 
I would like to change only color of overflow button.
If extra information needed please comment.

This is declaration of my toolbar:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/blue_background"
android:elevation="4dp">
```

This is my styles:

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBarStyle</item>
    <!--   your app branding color for the app bar -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/blue_background</item>
    <!--   darker variant for the status bar and contextual app bars -->
    <!--<item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>-->

    <!--   theme UI controls like checkboxes and text fields -->
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/search_button</item>

    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/search_button</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/search_button</item>
    <item name="android:logo">@drawable/dbc_logo_white</item>
    <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/menuOverflow</item>

</style>

<style name="menuOverflow" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/ic_action_overflow</item>
</style>
```

Comment: `ic_action_overflow` is image with your preferred color? @Sebastian

Comment: for now, yes... but if is other way to do this i dont have to use this image...

Comment: I don't understand too.. :( 
Here is my whole style file, maybe I don't see sth..:
http://pastebin.com/WED6DWgx

Comment: take a look to my reply!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay, I think I have the solution:

```
<!-- Overflow Button Style. -->
<item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/menuOverflow</item>
```

As you can see, remove `android:` before `actionOverFlowButtonStyle` in your style.

A lot of options with `android:` is not working pre-lollipop, you can try to remove some of them.

Comment: haha :) probably you make my day :) it works on my phone :) i do some more tests, if everything will be good i give you (Y) :)

Comment: Sorry for late (Y) :)

Comment: Actually I think you'd be better leaving both versions of the line for compatibility purpose (with and without the ```android:```)